# jQuery inner html from select option

Tags: jquery

I am writing a fancy select box with jquery, and have run into a little problem.

http://jsfiddle.net/kYhXn/

```
<select>
    <option>
        Shocka <br> Zooloo
     </option>
</select>​


alert($('option').html()+'');​
```

For whatever reason the `<br>` tag does not show up in the alert! How can I get the html with the `br` tag?

Pure js http://jsfiddle.net/z4Wb9/ same problem.

Comment: I can only assume that this is due to `<br>` being an invalid child of `<option>`.

Comment: `<option>` has a Text content model: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5-author/the-option-element.html#the-option-element -- this excludes any other elements.

Comment: Ok, good point. Can anyone think of a work around?

Comment: No workaround since the browser has discarded the `<br>` element.. open firebug and see the actual option.. no `<br>` in there..

Comment: Sure, so no <br> tag. What I need is some kind of token I can replace with a <br> tag in the fancy output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a workaround - you could use the invisible character *"`ALT+255`"* or ' ' and perform a replace:

```
//In the replace function, use the ' ' character and not just a space.
alert($('option').val().replace(' ','\n'));​
```

Or if you would like to replace every instance of the ALT+255 character with a new line, you would want to use:

```
alert($('option').val().replace(new RegExp(' ',g),'\n'));
```

Obviously this isn't very advisable, however it should work for your needs.

**[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/kYhXn/2/)**

### **Workaround Part 2**

Instead of using the `(null)` character, as previously suggested. Try using the `&ensp;` character as your token to perform the replace with, as shown:

```
 <option>
    Shocka&ensp;Zooloo
 </option>
```

You can copy the contents of this `( )` to access the character and the place that as the first argument in the replace function.

```
//The character being replace is NOT a normal space
alert($('option').val().replace(' ','\n'));​
```

**[Example Part 2](http://jsfiddle.net/kgUku/2/)**

Comment: tell me more about this `alt+255`

Comment: The ALT+255 character is an invisible character, you can use it by holding the ALT key and pressing 255. Stack Overflow doesn't allow it to be posted within the answer boxes, but if you check my example, you should be able to copy it out from between the two words in the box.

Comment: Ok, I've tried this and its not working as expected. What I am doing is `.replace(' ','<br>')` and it places the `<br>` at the location of my first white-space. As in simple space bar white space.

Comment: If you want to use a new line, you will want to use '\n' instead of the <br> tag. Also, within your <option> tags, you'll need to place the ALT+255 character wherever you would like your break to be. And the replace function should be exactly what is shown in the answer, .replace('(ALT+255)','\n'));

Comment: The ALT+255 character is acting as your token that you are going to be replacing with the new line.

Comment: The problem is that `.replace` does not respect the difference between ALT+255 and a simple space bar style white space.

Comment: Hmmm - it appears you are right. I'm trying to think of some other type of work around that you could use.

Comment: Okay - I think I figured this out, check out my updated answer.

Comment: Work around 2 is poyfect. Sir you are a gentalman and a scholar.